# .bash_profile has duplicates of the same line of code

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone help me out and tell me what is going on with my bash_profile. I'm not sure why it has so many repeats of the same lines of code.

What are the ^[ sections? At one point I was trying to set a shortcut for sublime text to open files, could this be from that? What would be the correct way to do that? Can I remove the duplicate lines of code without breaking something?

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[
"~/.bash_profile" 28L, 763C

# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[


# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~
~
~
~
~
# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~
~
~
~
# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~
~
~
~
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~
~
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~
~

# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~

# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~

# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~

# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~

# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~
~

# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~
~

# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

^[^[^[^[PATH=/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/ShareSupport/bin/subl
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

cd
ls
br
-br
-^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


~
~
~
~
-- INSERT --
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some Vim tomfoolery, typing commands in the wrong place, accidental copy-and-pasting, something like that.

`^[` is the character generated by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> in a program that doesn't handle it. `^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[` looks like someone mashing the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key trying to quit a program. Vim shouldn't do this, but other text editors might.

`"~/.bash_profile" 28L, 763C` is a typical status line from Vim. I'm guessing it was inadvertently copied-and-pasted from the screen into the file. Same goes for

```
~
~
~
~
-- INSERT --
```

The repeated copies could be due to a bunch of repeated pastes. That could be as simple as middle clicking the mouse a bunch of times, or pressing `p` repeatedly in Vim when not in insert mode.

Anyways, just go clean all this up. If you find yourself in Vim and have made a bunch of mistaken edits, a quick way out is to press <kbd>Escape</kbd> a couple of times, then type `:qa!`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. That's `q` for quit, `a` for all windows, and `!` for NO DO NOT SAVE JUST QUIT!